# Checking if the return is an int - Haskell

Tags: haskell, int

So what I would like to do is find out if the answer is an integer and return that answer. Here is an example. If I input 5, it would return 1.

The example checks if the integer is divisible by 5 or 6 and then returns it if it is.

```
division :: Int -> Int
division 5
    | 5 / 5 == Int || 5 / 6 == Int = Int
    | otherwise                    = 2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `mod`

```
f x | x `mod` 5 == 0 = x `div` 5
f x | x `mod` 6 == 0 = x `div` 6
f _ = 2
```

This will return x/5 if it is an int, if not, it will return x/6 if it is an int, else it will just return 2.

Comment: It is inelegant to use `mod` and `quot` together. Either use `mod` and `div`, or `rem` and `quot`.

Comment: @Sprout, surrounding the `mod` and `div` are backticks: a character usually located on the same key as the tilde, in the upper left of the keyboard (on US layout).